# Can we user butterknife and databinding together in a fragment?

Tags: android-databinding, butterknife

I am beginner to Android and I am working on a project, where the butterknife is used, I have to set the dark theme and light theme based on a user preference. I added databinding inorder to apply to the background and the test views based on the theme change. Is it okay to have butterknife and databinding in the same class.

Could you please help clarify.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it okay to have butterknife and databinding in the same class.

You can use both alongside in your project.

The downside is that both `butterknife` and `databinding` will be generating boilerplate code required for you.

But `databinding` gives has more benefits than `butterknife` and much more cleaner code also. `databinding` is much more advanced than `butterknife`. For more about [databinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) and also some blogs making head-to-head comparison [here](https://hackernoon.com/android-butterknife-vs-data-binding-fffceb77ed88) and [here](https://dev.to/ham8821/android-accessing-view-now-what-1jkg).

As officially announced for [Butterknife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife),

> Attention: This tool is now deprecated. Please switch to view binding. Existing versions will continue to work, obviously, but only critical bug fixes for integration with AGP will be considered. Feature development and general bug fixes have stopped.

The better way is to slowly start to get rid of `butterknife` and start using `databinding`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68230812/unable-to-use-in-local-variable-bindviews-not-applicable-to-local-variable-bu  pls check this question