# Unable to use in local variable '@BindViews' not applicable to local variable butterknife

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, butterknife

```
    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @BindViews(value = {R.id.logo, R.id.first, R.id.second, R.id.last})
  protected List<ImageView> sharedElements;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    @BindViews({R.id.pager)

    @BindViews(R.id.scrolling_background)
    final AnimatedViewPager pager = ButterKnife.findById(this, R.id.pager);
    final ImageView background = ButterKnife.findById(this, R.id.scrolling_background);
    int[] screenSize = screenSize();

    for (ImageView element : sharedElements) {
      @ColorRes int color = element.getId() != R.id.logo ? R.color.white_transparent : R.color.color_logo_log_in;
      DrawableCompat.setTint(element.getDrawable(), ContextCompat.getColor(this, color));
    }
```

authfragment

```
{
    public abstract class AuthFragment extends Fragment {
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
      }
      protected Callback callback;
    
      @BindView(R.id.caption)
      protected VerticalTextView caption;
    
      @BindView(R.id.root)
      protected ViewGroup parent;
    
      protected boolean lock;
    
    
    
      @Nullable
      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(authLayout(), container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, root);
        KeyboardVisibilityEvent.setEventListener(getActivity(), isOpen -> {
          callback.scale(isOpen);
          if (!isOpen) {
            clearFocus();
          }
        });
        return root;
      }
    
      public void setCallback(@NonNull Callback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
      }
    
      @LayoutRes
      public abstract int authLayout();
    
      public abstract void fold();
    
      public abstract void clearFocus();
    
      @OnClick(R.id.root)
      public void unfold() {
        if (!lock) {
          caption.setVerticalText(false);
          caption.requestLayout();
          Rotate transition = new Rotate();
          transition.setStartAngle(-90f);
          transition.setEndAngle(0f);
          transition.addTarget(caption);
          TransitionSet set = new TransitionSet();
          set.setDuration(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.duration));
          ChangeBounds changeBounds = new ChangeBounds();
          set.addTransition(changeBounds);
          set.addTransition(transition);
          TextSizeTransition sizeTransition = new TextSizeTransition();
          sizeTransition.addTarget(caption);
          set.addTransition(sizeTransition);
          set.setOrdering(TransitionSet.ORDERING_TOGETHER);
          caption.post(() -> {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parent, set);
            }
```

pls help me fix this error with butterknife . findbyid isnt also not available not able to use bindview pls help out with documentation or your code. so thats the authFragment now after some changes as suggested by GermliShx these error came maybe it my implementation  error so pls help me out. this is the login page with some animation idk y butterknife is creating problem her . i tried solving it but no luck this error is due to wrong implementation of butter knife so pls hel me out

Comment: `@BindViews({R.id.pager)`? And why inside a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove this:

```
    @BindViews({R.id.pager)
    @BindViews(R.id.scrolling_background)
... 
final AnimatedViewPager pager = ButterKnife.findById(this, R.id.pager);
    final ImageView background = ButterKnife.findById(this, R.id.scrolling_background);
```

Second add this:

```
    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        ...
       //binding is declared outside OnCreate / any other function

       //your case
        @BindView(R.id.pager)
            AnimatedViewPager pager;
            @BindView(R.id.scrolling_background)
            ImageView background ;

        ..
        //then in code just use declared pager and background when needed 
         @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              background .setColorFilter (R.color.black); //example 
        }
```

Should work, but I am not sure what AnimatedViewPager is.

It also may show `Resource IDs will be non-final in Android Gradle Plugin version 7.0, avoid using them as annotation attributes` warning, but you can just suppress it.

Try and reply how is it going.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/dDmSrWm   check this ss bro i have add this code in question ,

Comment: @GermlinShx thank you buddy , these error came now

Comment: @anshulraj try to change authlayout() to R.layout.name_fragment in View Root. Because this error happens when the compiler can't find your ids in a layout that you gave him.

Comment: i tried and read many documentation on butterknife but still couldnt solve it so pls it humble req can you once go through my code pls humble req i tried my whole brain but no success im still learning , its my school project   https://wetransfer.com/downloads/1ef06faa3e0a50b01bc1db4bc1ab5df020210714220741/f0e7be  (whole code here pls check humble request)

Comment: you can mail me back at anshul348567@gmail.com pls buddy its a small code of login and then a fragment activity